# Finding the exact value of a trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can someone please explain to me how i'm supposed to Find the exact value of cos (-210 degrees ).

Comment: That would be $\cos(-210^\circ)$ I suppose - it is **not** the same thing.  A good way to start would be to determine what quadrant the angle is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you meant degree measure, but when you leave it blank the general convention is that it's radian measure. That makes a ton of difference. You should always be clear to specify the unit.

Assuming you mean degrees,

$$\cos(-210^{\circ}) = \cos(210^{\circ}) = \cos(180+30)^{\circ} = -\cos 30^{\circ} = -\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

The first step is exploiting the even nature of the cosine function. The final step is simply remembering the trig ratios of the 30-60-90 degree triangle.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you mean degrees, but if not:

$$\cos(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} = 1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}- \cdots$$

Otherwise:

$$\cos(-210 ^\circ) = \cos(210^{\circ}) = \cos(180+30)^{\circ} \ \ \ (\text{recall}\  \cos(-x)=\cos(x))$$

$\cdot$ To finish up use angle addition for $\cos(x+y)$.

Comment: Taylor series is seriously (LOL) overkill for this problem, assuming the OP meant degree as the unit measure.

Comment: @Deepak: I've seen people place the tag algebraic geometry on a problem that required you to solve for $x$. I'm just trying to dot all i's here.

Comment: Your edit makes it the most complete answer. +1ed it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, cos(-210)=cos(150) because we can add and subtract 360. cos(150)=cos(180-30)
Next we know that, cos(a+b)=cos(a)cos(b)-sin(a)sin(b)
Thus, cos(180-30) = cos(180)cos(-30)-sin(180)sin(-30) = -cos(-30) - 0 = c-os(30) = $-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$